# Assigning an array of structs in another sruct

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

I have the following code:

```
struct sensor_data{
    uint8_t data_type;
    signed int data_left;
    uint8_t data_right;
};

struct sensor_payload{
    uint16_t key, id, type;
    uint8_t fields;
    struct sensor_data data[4];
    bool valid;

};
```

As you can see, `struct sensor_payload` has a `struct sensor_data[4]` inside of it. Basically, an array of structs within a struct.

When I try to assign it:

```
    uint16_t rcvd_key = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
    uint16_t rcvd_id = (buf[2] << 8) | buf[3];
    uint16_t rcvd_type = (buf[4] << 8) | buf[5];
    uint8_t rcvd_fields = buf[6];

    struct sensor_data rcvd_data[4];

    while(i <= (rcvd_fields)){
        rcvd_data[i].data_type = buf[j+7];
        rcvd_data[i].data_left = buf[j+8];
        rcvd_data[i].data_right = buf[j+9];

        i++;
        j = j + 3;
    }

    struct sensor_payload payload;
    payload.key = rcvd_key;
    payload.id = rcvd_id;
    payload.type = rcvd_type;
    payload.data = rcvd_data; <<LINE WITH ERROR
    payload.valid = true;
```

I get: `assignment to expression with array type`

Not even sure what the error means...

I tried this:

```
payload.data[0] = rcvd_data[0];
```

without changing ANY of the other code, and it compiles, but I am worried it's not the cleanest way to do it... Or the right way...

I have a feeling this problem is due to me not fully understanding pointers, or not seeing their use in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays can't be copied using the assignment operator `=`, so they can't be assigned to.
Use

1. A `for`-loop:

   ```
   for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(payload.data) / sizeof(*(payload.data)); ++i)
       payload.data[i] = rcvd_data[i];
   ```
2. Or `memcpy`:

   ```
   memcpy(payload.data, rcvd_data, sizeof(payload.data));
   ```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself some time and trouble but writing the data directly into the payload structure, like this

```
struct sensor_payload payload;

payload.key    = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
payload.id     = (buf[2] << 8) | buf[3];
payload.type   = (buf[4] << 8) | buf[5];
payload.fields =  buf[6];

j = 7;
for ( i = 0; i < 4 && i < payload.fields; i++ )
{
    payload.data[i].data_type  = buf[j++];
    payload.data[i].data_left  = buf[j++];
    payload.data[i].data_right = buf[j++];
}

payload.valid = true;
```